# How can I get the media files of a product in Shopware 6 using store-api?

Tags: shopware6-api

we have some problem with store-api. When i request a specific product the media is empty. I need to have all the product’s image. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it would be best to start any question with what you have attempted already, to see if you are missing some part of the puzzle.

Here is a short gist of the request you need:

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'http://website.com/store-api/product' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'sw-access-key: XXX' \
--data-raw '{
   "limit": 1,
   "includes": {
       "product": ["cover", "media"]
   },
   "associations": {
       "media": {}
   }
}'
```

Sometimes the data that you are looking for requires an extra database JOIN call. In your case it's the `media` table, hence why you need to use [associations](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/search-criteria#associations) to make sure the query joins that table to your response.

P.S. you don't have to use `includes`, I just used it to shorten the response object.